# Source Filmmarker to Blender import

Tags: texturing, import

I imported this model from Source Filmmarker to Blender, any reason why the eyebrow texture looks like this? The block shows up in render also.

If anyone could point me in the right direction to fixing this I will research and figure it out, or if  you want to tell me how to fix it that would be great too. Appreciate the help.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Every face in a mesh model can be assigned a different material. By face I am referring to the polygons of the mesh, not the characters face.

The model would appear to have one material for the skin and another for eyebrows and eyelashes. This probably allows choosing different eyebrow textures to get a variety of characters.

I expect both materials are meant to use an [image texture](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/render/blender_render/textures/introduction.html) to define the colour on the model. Either the images are missing or are not set to be used by the material.